# Number and placement of posts and footings (12" diameter) for a 40' x 12' deck

Tags: deck, footings

I'm building a 40' 8.25" x 12' deck attached to the house via a ledger on the longer side. The max distance from the ground to the bottom of the ledge is 65.25". Here's a screen grab of my current design. *(For the purposes of this question please ignore the floating sliding door on the left)*

[image: 40' x 12' Deck with 70 psf support]

While I can set a few variables such as live (40 psf) and dead (10 psf) load I am unable to select soil type, post size, or pier and footing dimensions. I am therefore concerned that the suggested 6 posts with 12" diameter footings would be insufficient to support this load on my soil (clay).

My rough calculations show I need at least 10 footings to spread the load out. For my calculations I am assuming clay soil that can support 1500 psf (some references indicate it can support 2000 psf).

- Deck Load = 40' * 12' * (10 psf + 40 psf) = **24,000 lbs**
- Load Supported By Footings = (24,000 / 2) = **12,000 lbs**
- Square feet per footing = pi * 0.5^2 = **0.785 sqft**
- Max lbs per footing = 1500 psf (clay) * 0.785 = **1177.5 lbs**
- Approx Number of footings = 12,000 lbs / 1177.5 = **10 footings**

Are my calculations off? What else should I consider? These are roughly based off of the [decksgo.com deck load capacity page](https://www.decksgo.com/deck-load-capacity.html).

Here is some additional info that may be relevant.

- 6" x 6" posts
- 2" x 10" beams
- 12" diameter pier + footing (via sonotube concrete form)
- 48" depth *(per recommendations from local permitting office)*
- Primarily clay soil
- Snow during winter months
- Local area = mid-coast Maine

**Bonus round**

Should I need the additional footings, would it make sense to place them all along the front of the deck, or should I have half at the front and half between the ledger and the front footings?

If they should be split into two rows should they form a perfect grid or should the middle row be slightly staggered left or right from the front row? Strong-Tie staggers the additional posts when increasing the load as seen below.

[image: 40' x 12' Deck with 80 psf support]

Comment: Usually posts are space so that a beam can safety span the distance between them.  As an example a beam made from two or three 2x10s should span 10 feet safety, so four posts needed(this is a rule of thumb/napkin math design).  You build from the bottom up, but design from the top down.

Comment: @crip659 40', 10' span = **5** posts.

Comment: Aren't the number of posts that are required based primarily on supporting the dead and live load based on the soil type? That is what I am looking for, given clay, how many posts with 12" footings are required to support this load, and what is their spacing.

Comment: @RyanTaylor have you checked with your local building dept to see what they require?

Comment: @Huesmann, I have but they have not yet responded to my email (sent ~1 week ago).

Comment: @RyanTaylor do they have a website?  My county has their deck requirements in a PDF on their website.  It's probably a very common inquiry.

Comment: @Huesmann, they do but there are no deck requirement documents. We're a pretty small town < 2000 people. We have an intent to build form to obtain a permit but no code enforcement documents. We don't have deck inspections here, they are really only concerned with inspections for utilities. I did find this guide on r/decks which may be helpful. https://www.reddit.com/r/Decks/comments/v9nzy7/american_deck_standards/

Comment: Then my best guess is that you should follow the deck guidelines in whatever IRC version your town/county follows (that Reddit doc is based on 2015 IRC).